# How to use boost::compute::atan2?

Tags: opencl, boost-compute

I would like to compute the phase of a complex number using boost::compute

here is my attempt, I expect the result to be equal to atan2(0.5f):

```
namespace bc = boost::compute;

bc::vector<std::complex<float>> vec{ {1.0f, 2.0f} };
bc::vector<float> result(1);
bc::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), result.begin(), bc::atan2<float>());
```

but I get a compilation error claiming "Non-unary function invoked one argument"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can also use Boost.Compute's lambda expressions for this:

```
  bc::vector<float2> input{ {1.0f, 2.0f}, {3.0f, 4.0f}, {5.0f, 6.0f} };
  bc::vector<float> output(3); 

  using boost::compute::lambda::atan2;
  using boost::compute::_1;
  using boost::compute::lambda::get;

  bc::transform(
    float2_input.begin(),
    float2_input.end(),
    float_output.begin(),
    atan2(get<1>(_1), get<0>(_1)),
    queue
  );
```

`float2` is bassically a complex in Boost.Compute.  You can also check [test_lambda.cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/test/test_lambda.cpp).

Answer (score 2):

`boost::compute`'s `atan2` [would appear to be a binary function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/compute/lambda/functional.hpp) just like [`std::atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2).

I'm assuming you're trying to obtain the phase angle of your complex number? The standard C++ function for this would be [`std::arg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/arg) - I don't see this one being defined in `boost::compute`, though I might have missed it.

If `arg()` is indeed missing, you're quite right it's implemented via `atan2` - you'll need to extract the imaginary (`boost::compute::imag()`) and real (`boost::compute::real()`) components first though, and pass them as individual arguments to `atan2`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to deduce working code from your answer. Could you please add a small example?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work.

stage 1: allocate 2 vectors:

```
bc::vector<std::complex<float>> vec{ {1.0f, 2.0f}, {3.0f, 4.0f}, {5.0f, 6.0f} };
bc::vector<float> result(3);
```

stage 2: interpret the complex vector as a float buffer iterator

`buffer_iterator` is quite useful when you have a strongly typed vector and would like to pass it to an algorithm as a different type.

```
auto beginf = bc::make_buffer_iterator<float>(vec.get_buffer(), 0);
auto endf = bc::make_buffer_iterator<float>(vec.get_buffer(), 6); // note end point to final index + 1
```

stage 3: define strided iterators so that we can use the same buffer as the argument for tan2. each iterator iterates the buffers in strides of 2 indices, and they supply tan2 with interleaved access to the buffer:

```
auto begin_a = bc::make_strided_iterator(beginf + 1, 2); // access imaginary part
auto end_a = bc::make_strided_iterator_end(beginf + 1, endf , 2);
auto begin_b = bc::make_strided_iterator(beginf, 2); // access real part
```

finally, call transform:

```
bc::transform(begin_a, end_a, begin_b, result.begin(), bc::atan2<float>()); // atan(b/a)
bc::system::default_queue().finish();
```